# Why does Google Analytics prefix so many values (as opposed to keys) with "ga:"?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

It seems a bit redundant in places. Could it not just be excluded? I'm wondering from an API design point of view.

For example, the ViewId is "is in the format of ga:XXXX, where XXXX" at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#view_ids

The metrics expression is "ga:users" at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#introduction

eg.

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "reportRequests":[
  {
    "viewId":"XXXX",
    "dateRanges":[
    {
      "startDate":"2015-11-01",
      "endDate":"2015-11-06"
    }],
    "metrics":[
    {
      "expression":"ga:users"
    },{
      "expression":"ga:sessions"
    }],
    ...
  }]
}
```

Same for dimensions, etc.

Comment: You can use the [alias field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Metric) for metrics if you truly want to ditch the ga: prefix, but the alias field really comes in handy if you have complicated metricExpression. But Eric is right the prefix is to distinguish various API dimensions with the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's namespacing to distinguish names for metrics and dimension from similar names in other APIs. For example both the Core Reporting API and the Realtime API have a dimension "medium", and you can easily see which API is used when your see ga:medium versus rt:medium, "rt" being the prefix that indicates Realtime API queries.